# How to blend two DrawNodes in cocos2d

Tags: c++, c++11, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-2.x

I need some help with cocos2d DrawNodes blending. I have DrawNode with sprite on it:

[image]
And another DrawNode with drawn polygon (polygon area is less than heart sprite). As a result of blending I need to have only a part of heart sprite inside polygon, like this:
[image]
My code:
TextureNode.h

```
class CTextureNode : public cocos2d::DrawNode
{
public:
static CTextureNode * create(const std::string & fileName, const cocos2d::Rect & rect);

CTextureNode();
virtual ~CTextureNode();

void setPolygonalMask(const cocos2d::Vec2 * verts, int count);

private:
bool initTexture(const std::string & fileName, const cocos2d::Rect & rect);

private:
cocos2d::DrawNode * m_pMask;
cocos2d::Sprite * m_pSprite;

float timeOutline;
bool bShaderInc;
};
```

TextureNode.cpp

```
CTextureNode * CTextureNode::create(const std::string & fileName, const cocos2d::Rect & rect)
{
auto ret = new CTextureNode();
if (!ret || !ret->init() || !ret->initTexture(fileName, rect))
{
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(ret);
}

return ret;
}

CTextureNode::CTextureNode()
: timeOutline(0.f)
, bShaderInc(true)
, m_pMask(nullptr)
, m_pSprite(nullptr)
{
}

CTextureNode::~CTextureNode()
{
}

bool CTextureNode::initTexture(const std::string & fileName, const cocos2d::Rect & rect)
{
m_pSprite = cocos2d::Sprite::create(fileName, rect);
m_pSprite->setAnchorPoint(cocos2d::Point::ZERO);
addChild(m_pSprite);

m_pMask = cocos2d::DrawNode::create();
m_pMask->setPosition(cocos2d::Point::ZERO);
m_pMask->setAnchorPoint(cocos2d::Point::ZERO);
addChild(m_pMask);

return true;
}

void CTextureNode::setPolygonalMask(const cocos2d::Vec2 * verts, int count)
{
if (m_pMask)
{
    m_pMask->drawPolygon(verts, count, cocos2d::Color4F::WHITE, 1, cocos2d::Color4F::WHITE);

    cocos2d::BlendFunc maskBlendFunc = { GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA };
    m_pMask->setBlendFunc(maskBlendFunc);

    auto size = m_pSprite->getContentSize();

    auto renderer = cocos2d::RenderTexture::create(size.width, size.height, cocos2d::Texture2D::PixelFormat::RGBA8888);
    renderer->begin();

    m_pMask->visit();

    renderer->end();
}
}
```

As a result of this code I see full hart sprite without polygon. I also try to change BlendFunc values, but it not help.
Please tell me what I do wrang)

P.S. Thanks!
P.S.P.S. Sorry for my english)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. You want to mask a sprite with polygon? Post some preview how should it look like.

Comment: @Makalele I have node with sprite (gray heart) on it and another node with drawn polygon. Size of second node is less than first one. I need to blend this nodes. Result of blending - polygon from second node with sprite from first node inside it (on second picture it is area inside red polygon).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to clip the heart sprite using the polygon as a stencil. In that case. You don't have to blend two `DrawNode`. Instead, You can use `ClippingNode` like:

```
auto heartSprite = cocos2d::Sprite::create(fileName);

auto stencil = DrawNode::create();
stencil->drawPolygon(verts, count, cocos2d::Color4F::WHITE, 1, cocos2d::Color4F::WHITE);

auto clipper = ClippingNode::create();
clipper->setStencil(stencil);
clipper->addChild(heartSprite)
```

For more `ClippingNode` examples, you can refer to the official sample code: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/tree/v3/tests/cpp-tests/Classes/ClippingNodeTest

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I need to do it by using renderer and blending functions